# TreeView Control ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a treeview control on an asp page. Everytime I select a node, be it root node or child node, the entire tree is displayed again under the tree. If I go on selecting nodes on the tree, no matter which one I select, a duplicate tree is displayed under it. I have written no events so far. It is some property that I am missing out on. Please help!

Comment: Could you please post your code so we can help you? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is this tree being created on page load by any chance? If so, test (!`isPostback`) on `PageLoad` in code behind before creating it. If not, then you need to provide more code. Include details of event handlers for the control etc.